# Google Compute Engine deletes VM Instance automatically

Tags: google-compute-engine, lamp, debian-based

I have used Google Compute Engine for my backend (debian-lamp), suddenly it gets deleted automatically without any user interaction and also doesn't shows the operation(Deletion of VM Instance ) performed by which user. I have also attached the image of Google Compute Engine Operations for further study.

I want to know why does this happened and what are the ways to restore the deleted instance.

**Note:** I am using trial version of Google Compute Engine and this was my second VM Instance created in Current Project.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you are using Preemptible instances by mistake?

Comment: Nope, I am using Standard persistent disk .

Comment: Not the disk, the instance itself- see [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#checking_if_an_instance_is_preemptible)

Comment: sorry about that, but i checked that too Preemptible version is OFF.Availability policies

 Preemptibility 
Off (recommended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the instance was deleted by the Instance Group Manager after you resized the instance group (most likely to zero). To learn about why this happened, visit the docs pages for [Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) and the [Instance Group Manager](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/manager/).

If you resize the Instance Group back up to 1, the Instance Group Manager will create a new VM automatically.

Comment: I also have an auto scaled instance group with only one instance in it for the moment and it seems to be deleted and new one inserted somewhat randomly (or so it appears) sometimes multiple times a day. Is this normal maintenance behavior or does it have to do with an unhealthy instance? Reason I don't suspect the latter is because before auto scaling, it was running fine without intervention for long periods with the same code. thanks.